# Cant update avatar in tableview + uiimagepickerController

Tags: swift, tableview, uiimagepickercontroller

I have a tableViewcell with imageView for avatar and I using TapGestureRecognizer in my viewController to change avatar, but after I pick photo my avatar still without photo. Just white. maybe I should reload something?

I have cell with imageView and I using TapGestureRecognizer in my viewController to change avatar, but after I pick photo my avatar still without photo. Just white. maybe I should reload something?

[image: Image of viewcontroller]

```
extension BarberSettingsViewController: UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate {

    func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [UIImagePickerController.InfoKey : Any]) {
        var selectedImageFromPicker: UIImage?
        if let editedImage = info[.editedImage] as? UIImage  {
            selectedImageFromPicker = editedImage
            picker.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
        } else {
            let originalImage = info[.originalImage] as! UIImage
            selectedImageFromPicker = originalImage
            picker.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
        }

        if let selectedImage = selectedImageFromPicker {
            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: UserAvatarCell.name) as! UserAvatarCell
            cell.avatarImageView.image = selectedImage
        }
    }


    func imagePickerControllerDidCancel(_ picker: UIImagePickerController) {
        picker.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Declare this code above the viewdidLoad()

var img : UIImage? {
        didSet{

```
        tableView.reloadData()
    }
}
```

Then  add this line on cellForRow Method of table view

cell.imageView.Image = img

And  change this function

func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [UIImagePickerController.InfoKey : Any]) {
        var selectedImageFromPicker: UIImage?
        if let editedImage = info[.editedImage] as? UIImage  {
            selectedImageFromPicker = editedImage
            picker.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
        } else {
            let originalImage = info[.originalImage] as! UIImage
            selectedImageFromPicker = originalImage
            picker.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
        }

```
    if let selectedImage = selectedImageFromPicker {
        img = selectedImage

    }
}
```

Comment: GOD BLESS YOU!  GOD BLESS YOU!

Answer (score 0):

Please reload table view after set image on cell

tableview.reloadData()

If there are multiple section then you reload that particular section or row of table tableview.

Comment: After this line you reload let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: UserAvatarCell.name) as! UserAvatarCell
        cell.avatarImageView.image = selectedImage

Comment: I exactly did the same.         if let selectedImage = selectedImageFromPicker {
            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: UserAvatarCell.name) as! UserAvatarCell
            cell.avatarImageView.image = selectedImage
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.tableView.reloadData()
            }
        }

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is this part

```
if let selectedImage = selectedImageFromPicker {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: UserAvatarCell.name) as! UserAvatarCell 
        // this is an empty cell, 
        cell.avatarImageView.image = selectedImage
    }
```

You should get cell from presented table view with cell index, your code create a new cell but you should add avatar to presented cell

```
let cell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath) as! UserAvatarCell

cell.avatarImageView.image = selectedImage
```